# Is there a way to build an HTTP proxy on AWS using API gateway for a 3rd party domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-proxy

I'm trying to build an API proxy that forwards all endpoints and params to a 3rd party domain.

So if I make these request:

```
my-arn.amazonaws.com
my-arn.amazonaws.com/api
my-arn.amazonaws.com/api/resource?query=string
```

It should forward them as follows, respectively:

```
thirdparty.example
thirdparty.example/api
thirdparty.example/api/resource?query=string
```

Is this possible using API Gateway?

Comment: You can do this with CloudFront...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!! it is one of the use cases why API Gateway exists.

Im summary you just need to create your API Gateway REST API and use integration type HTTP_PROXY. You will also need to configure your mapping templates.

You can find more information about how to do it in the [Official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with API gateway integration type as HTTP_PROXY.
Mapping templates are not really necessary for proxy integrations. If you would like to change any parameters (request headers, query parametes etc) then you would require mapping templates.
Mapping Templates : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html